# How do I switch back to automatically showing variable values in the PyCharm debugger?

Tags: pycharm, debuggervisualizer

I have a PyCharm project in which my `__str__` values were taking a long time to calculate. The value display in the debugger window was timing out, so PyCharm prompted me in the debugger window to switch to not automatically showing the value. I selected this. Now my debugger window looks like this.

[image: Debugger window with prompt required]

I have to click on "Show Value" to make the debugger calculate and display the value.

I fixed the slow `__str__` code, so now I want to go back to automatically showing the value. My Preferences settings look like this.

[image: Preferences window]

I would expect that since "Enable auto expressions in Variables view" is checked, I should no longer be seeing "Show Value" in the Variables view, but that is not the case.

I have tried exiting and restarting PyCharm to no effect. Other PyCharm projects still do automatically display the variable values, so I presume I made some project-specific change, but I can't figure out how to reverse it.

How do I go back to automatically displaying variable values in the Variables view for this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to select options menu on the debug toolbar (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html#debugtoolbar) and switch `Variables Loading Policy` to `Synchronously` or `Asynchronously`.